# Thinking Sphinx: Another index error

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, thinking-sphinx

While indexing I get this error:

```
indexing index 'qtl_table_core'...
ERROR: index 'qtl_table_core': sql_range_query: 'soybase.qtl_table.QTLName' isn't in GROUP BY (DSN=mysql://_www:***@xxxxxxx/soybase).
```

My model:

```
class QtlTable < ActiveRecord::Base
   ....
  define_index do
    indexes :QTLID, :sortable => true
    indexes :QTLName, :sortable => true
  end
```

development.sphinx.conf

```
indexer
{
}

searchd
{
  listen = 127.0.0.1:1234
  log = /usr/home/benjamin/qtl/log/searchd.log
  query_log = /usr/home/benjamin/qtl/log/searchd.query.log
  pid_file = /usr/home/benjamin/qtl/log/searchd.development.pid
}

source qtl_table_core_0
{
  type = mysql
  sql_host = xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  sql_user = _www
  sql_pass =
  sql_db = soybase
  sql_query_pre = SET NAMES utf8
  sql_query_pre = SET TIME_ZONE = '+0:00'
  sql_query = SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE `qtl_table`.`QTLID` * CAST(1 AS SIGNED) + 0 AS `QTLID` , `qtl_table`.`QTLID` AS `QTLID`, `qtl_table`.`QTLName` AS `QTLName`, `qtl_table`.`QTLID` AS `sphinx_internal_id`, 0 AS `sphinx_deleted`, 1786069111 AS `class_crc`, IFNULL(`qtl_table`.`QTLID`, '') AS `QTLID_sort`, IFNULL(`qtl_table`.`QTLName`, '') AS `QTLName_sort` FROM `qtl_table` WHERE (`qtl_table`.`QTLID` >= $start AND `qtl_table`.`QTLID` <= $end) GROUP BY `qtl_table`.`QTLID` ORDER BY NULL
  sql_query_range = SELECT IFNULL(MIN(`QTLID`), 1), IFNULL(MAX(`QTLID`), 1) FROM `qtl_table`
  sql_attr_uint = sphinx_internal_id
  sql_attr_uint = sphinx_deleted
  sql_attr_uint = class_crc
  sql_attr_str2ordinal = QTLID_sort
  sql_attr_str2ordinal = QTLName_sort
  sql_query_info = SELECT * FROM `qtl_table` WHERE `QTLID` = (($id - 0) / 1)
}

index qtl_table_core
{
  source = qtl_table_core_0
  path = /usr/home/benjamin/qtl/db/sphinx/development/qtl_table_core
  charset_type = utf-8
  min_infix_len = 1
  enable_star = 1    
}

index qtl_table
{
  type = distributed
  local = qtl_table_core
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the following inside your `define_index` block:

```
group_by "`qtl_table`.`QTLName`"
```

Comment: I figured this out a long time ago and just now noticed you provided the correct answer :) points for you